# Why QML Connections does not work here?

Tags: qt, qml

I am learning QML and designing an hybrid QML/C++ application that will run on an embedded Linux.

So far i have 4 pages (`Page0.qml`, `Page1.qml`, `Page2.qml`, `Page3.qml`) and i am trying to navigate amongst them with a `StackView`.

All qml files are in a `qml.qrc` ressource file.

Each `Page` is defined like this :

```
// Page0.qml
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Page {
    id: root

    signal pageRequested(string pageUrl)

    background: Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "orange"
    }

    Button {
        text: "Page 1"
        width: 100
        height: 100
        anchors.top: text.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: text.horizontalCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 10
        onClicked: { 
            console.log("Button clicked")
            root.pageRequested("PAGESGRP1/Page1.qml")
        }
    }

    Label {
        id: text
        text: "You are on Page 0."
        font.pointSize: 25
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }    
}
```

and the main page is :

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
// qml files are not in the directory of main.qml
// that's why i have these "import" statement
import "PAGESWELCOME" // Page0.qml
import "PAGESGRP1" // Page1.qml
import "PAGESGRP2" // Page2.qml
import "PAGESGRP3" //Page3.qml

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true

    Item {
        id: baseItem
        rotation: 90
        width: 1024
        height: 1280
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Page0 {
            id: page0
        }

        Page1 {
            id: page1
        }

        Page2 {
            id: page2
        }

        Page3 {
            id: page3
        }

        StackView {
            id: stackView
            initialItem: "PAGESWELCOME/Page0.qml"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Connections {
            target: page0
            onPageRequested: { // This signal handler is never called 
                console.log("Page 0 request page : " + pageUrl)
                stackView.push(Qt.resolvedUrl(pageUrl))
            }
        }

        Connections {
            target: page1
            onPageRequested: {
                console.log("Page 1 request page : " + pageUrl)
                stackView.push(Qt.resolvedUrl(pageUrl))
            }
        }

        Connections {
            target: page2
            onPageRequested: { 
                console.log("Page 2 request page : " + pageUrl)
                stackView.push(Qt.resolvedUrl(pageUrl))
            }
        }

        Connections {
            target: page3
            onPageRequested: {
                console.log("Page 3 request page : " + pageUrl)
                stackView.push(Qt.resolvedUrl(pageUrl))
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My problem is that the `StackView` always stays on `Page0`. Nothing happens after a button click.

From http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html#details

> More generally, the Connections object can be a child of some object
>   other than the sender of the signal:

What is the correct way to do it ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the target property of your `Connections` element to the StackView directly:

```
Connections {
    target: stackView.currentItem

    onPageRequested: { // This signal handler is never called
        console.log("Page 0 request page : " + pageUrl)
        stackView.push(Qt.resolvedUrl(pageUrl))
    }
}
```

So you can remove all other `Connections` elements from your "PageX" container component.

**Edit:** (hint from eyllanesc)

You can remove your PageX { } elements completely from your `main.qml`. They are not used because you do not push this elements on `StackView` but instanciate a new one from passed Qml Url.

Because of this your `Connections` containers are not working.

Comment: and it should also be noted that the PageX {...} created in the .qml are not the objects shown in the stackView

Comment: I recommend you point out that in your question, I think it is the most important thing for the author to understand why his solution fails.